# Horizontal scroll on mobile device website layout

Tags: html, css

I am getting horizontal scroll on my HTML website layout all of a sudden and I cannot figure out how or why. Any tips?

Comment: You can use `overflow-x: hidden`

Comment: I think you might find [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76351000/17497724) helpful.

Comment: Hi @dylanhibbert , can you please provide more details like Chrome version, mobile device view, screenshot and html code for your empty page. That will help us to understand the issue more clearly. If possible then please provide the steps to replicate the issue. Thanks

Comment: @AngelUmeh could you please specify your browser type and version, and operating system. A completely blank page (i.e. `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`) should not have any horizontal or vertical scrolling - and indeed does not for the great majority of browsers and browser configurations.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when an element's width is greater than the viewport width. This could be caused by text flowing outside of a container or another incorrectly sized element.

## Good Fix

Use the inspector and start deleting elements one by one, eventually you'll delete an element that will remove the horizontal scroll. Note that you can CTRL-Z to undelete an element in the inspector. Once you've found the offending element you can inspect/adjust it's styles to fix the overflow.

## Cheat Fix

Add `overflow-x: hidden;` styling to your `body` element.

This is not advisable though as it's not fixing the overflowing element, instead it's hiding the part that overflows.

Comment: none of these ever work

I could have a brand, completely empty new page and it would have horizontal scroll out of nowhere. I haven't put anything on it at all TT

Comment: hey @AngelUmeh, this happened because default `viewport` in HTML basicaly purposed for desktop layout. So you can add meta viewport on Kedmun's answer below here.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes some elements take fixed width more than screen size find that element and change its with in media query or try to give `max width: 100%`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you say hiding the overflow does **not** work. However, have you tried targeting mobile specific screen widths within your CSS and then applying the `overflow-x: hidden;` to your `body` tag.

You're able to do this with CSS `@media` rules.
You can view more on this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Do you also have this;

> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

in your `<head>` tag? It's a widely popular practice that solves a lot of responsive webpage issues.

If you could provide us with some of the code you're having issues with, users might be able to get more of an insight into your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can first, check for issues in your CSS if there are some properties that are set incorrectly and it's causing the problem.

If not, then you should check for:

1. Overflowing Content: Make sure you don't have any elements which are wider or leaving their container. You can try using the `overflow-x: hidden` property on the parent to hide any overflowing.
2. Developer tools: you can use the browser's developer tools to find the elements that are causing the horizontal scroll and also check if the same issue persists in other browsers. Sometimes it can be horizontal scrolling and can be browser specific. If yes, it can be resolved by adjusting your CSS or using browser-specific CSS.

Answer (score 0):

try setting your viewport meta in your HTML head as follows

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

hopefully it works