# horizontal scroll persistently on website

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Whenever I'm creating a website with HTML & CSS, I find that the site acquires a horizontal scroll. On inspection with Chrome DevTools, I never see what is causing the issue. All the elements are always within the page and none of them generate boxes that extend outside of the page. Even without any elements on screen, there would be a horizontal scroll; the effect is especially persistent on mobile screens. I might be able to make the scroll disappear on a large screen like a laptop by doing either

```css
body {
    width: 95vw;
}
```

and/or

```css
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

but it never goes away on mobile. The result is a slight, annoying, left-right motion on any website I ever make, like the following:

- [landing page for a fictional agency (Frontend Mentor project)](https://akcumeh.github.io/03-sunnyside)
- [a feature section component (Frontend Mentor project)](https://akcumeh.github.io/02-fourcard-feature-section-redo)
- [an order summary component (Frontend Mentor project)](https://akcumeh.github.io/04-order-summary-component)
- [My hobby website](https://angelcrochet.com)

and pretty much every other responsive website I've ever built that has a mobile design.

I've scoured the internet for solutions and I've gotten things like 'use `box-sizing: border-box;`', 'remove/resize any overflowing elements', etc. I also came up with the fix I mentioned above involving `width: 95vw;` for the `body` element. I've also searched this platform for answers and come across some, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71685205/17497724), that make me wonder if the answerers have ever actually come across the problem in their own code before. None of these solutions actually ever work and I'm curious as to how everyone else makes websites that *don't* have this nagging horizontal scroll in their websites.

So here's how to reproduce the issue.

```html
<body>
    <main>
        stuff
    </main>
    <footer>
        feet
    </footer>
</body>
```

```css
/* General Styles */
@media screen
    and (min-width: 300px)
    and (orientation: portrait), (orientation: landscape) {
body {
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 86%);
    color: hsl(0, 0%, 8%);
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
}
```

When created, view the website on Chrome DevTools on a mobile phone's dimensions whether iPhone or any other kind of phone. Tap and hold  the site and drag it around.

Would really appreciate a lasting fix for this

Comment: Are you aware that browsers may add e.g. margins by default to some elements? You should be able to see this when using your browser's devtools inspect facility by looking at the CSS applied for example to the body element. One thing to do is to set margin: 0 for all elements at the head of your stylesheet and then just apply margins when you need them specifically.

Comment: Yeah, I've noticed the default margins before and this is why I usually set `body { margin: 0 !important; }` at the head of stylesheets... most times it doesn't work; besides, I'm told using the !important flag is bad practice

Comment: I would set all to margin 0, not just body, and I would not use important. If this is your own code it will give you control of margin settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this, what it will do is remove whatever is exceding the body:**

```
width: 100vw !important;
overflow-x: clip !important;
```

do not use `overflow-x: hidden` as still it will not stop the children from going out of boundaries. I tried applying the above code on your websites, and it works.

Comment: Okay. I do use the !important flag but I've been told it's not best practice... and most times it doesn't even work. however, I had no idea `clip` was a possible value for `overflow` property. So I'll go try that now

Comment: it some gets messy, but it normal scenario it will work.

Comment: It seems to work now. I'll see how it holds up. Thank you!

Comment: welcome, kindly mark the answer correct once you find it works..